# nth-child(2) does not select element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a grid where the section header takes up three columns of the first row, and three different blocks take up the second row, each taking up one column. I successfully selected the second and third feature blocks with `nth-child`, but I am unable to select the first feature block (the background-color does not apply to the first column). Is there something I am missing out?

I attempted giving each of them an id to select with CSS, and it works. But I am trying to figure out why the `nth-child` selector does not work here.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-section .header-block {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
}

.feature-block {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  color: blue;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-section">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header-block">
      <h1>Uncanny Valley</h1>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Pseudo classes select elements, not classes of elements. When you add a class it acts like a filter on the selector, further limiting it. Your `nth-child(2)` and `nth-child(3)` work only because they're matching the 2nd and 3rd children, not because of the classes you added to the elements or selectors

Answer (score 2):

nth-child select element by position in parent block
Example: .grid .feature-block:nth-child(3)  -  in this case we looking for  third element in .grid with class feature-block, but not third .feature-block.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-section .header-block {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
}

.feature-block {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  color: blue;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid .feature-block:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3/4;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-section">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header-block">
      <h1>Uncanny Valley</h1>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images
        In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images
        In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images
        In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-block">
      <div class="feature-image"></div>
      <h2>Mori's Hypothesis</h2>
      <p class="copy">
        An empirically estimated uncanny valley for static robot face images
        In aesthetics.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: A thorough explanation would be far more useful than "That what you wanted?"

Comment: Why did this work? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Example: .grid .feature-block:nth-child(3)  -  in this case we looking for  third element in .grid with class feature-block, but not third .feature-block. nth-child select element by position in parent block